# Array not passing values to for loop

Tags: arrays, unix, for-loop

I have code like below, Array not passing values to for loop.

```
echo "rops is ${rops[*]}"
for i in ${rops[*]}
do
if [[ ${rops[i]} == 4000 ]]; then
echo "issue there"
 fi
 done
```

### Below is script run in debug mode

```
+ echo 'rops is 931
  32
 32'
 rops is 931
  32
   32
 + for i in '${rops[*]}'
   + [[ '' == 4000 ]]
  + for i in '${rops[*]}'
   + [[ '' == 4000 ]]
  + for i in '${rops[*]}'
  + [[ '' == 4000 ]]
```

-Thanks.

Comment: Which shell are you using?  How did you assign to `rops`?  Was the indentation in debug mode really that erratic?  Please note that this is not an MCVE ([MCVE]) because you don't show how `rops` is initialized.

Comment: Here is the exact code

`rops=(5 10 20 2500)  
echo "rops is ${rops[*]}"  

for i in ${rops[@]}  
do  

if [[ ${rops[i]} == 4000 ]]; then  
echo "issue there"  
fi  
done`

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that `i` contains a value from the array, not an index into the array.

That is, the first time `i` is `931`, then `32`, then `31`, but you don't have elements `${rops[931]}`, `${rops[32]}` or `${rops[31]}`, so the shell gives you an empty string as the value of `${rops[i]}` (which should be `${rops[$i]}` anyway).  So, there are multiple reasons why the shell is doing what it is.

```
rops=(931 32 31)
echo "rops is ${rops[*]}"
for i in ${rops[*]}
do
    echo "i = $i"
    if [[ "${rops[$i]}" == 4000 ]]; then
        echo "issue there"
    fi
done
```

When run with `bash`, that yields:

```
rops is 931 32 31
i = 931
i = 32
i = 31
```

The difference in the spacing indicates that you didn't initialize the array exactly like this code does; you somehow got newlines associated with the array elements.

Using the notation `for i in ${rops[*]}` (or `for i in "${rops[@]}"`, which is better on multiple levels — try using array elements with spaces in the values to see why) gives the elements in the array.  If you really want the indexes, you need to read the Bash manual on [arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) and use:

```
rops=(931 32 31)
echo "rops is ${rops[*]}"
echo "indexes are ${!rops[*]}"
for i in "${!rops[@]}"
do
    echo "i = $i; rops[$i] = ${rops[$i]}"
    if [[ "${rops[$i]}" == 4000 ]]; then
        echo "issue there"
    fi
done
```

Sample output:

```
rops is 931 32 31
indexes are 0 1 2
i = 0; rops[0] = 931
i = 1; rops[1] = 32
i = 2; rops[2] = 31
```

Comment: `rops=(931 32 31)  
echo "rops is ${rops[*]}"  
for i in ${rops[*]}  
do  
    echo "j = $i"  
    if [[ "${rops[$i]}" == 4000 ]]; then  
        echo "issue there"  
    fi  
done  `
I changed as you suggested above, still values from array not passed to for loop.

Comment: Well, since `$i` contains `931` and there isn't an element `${rops[931]}` (you only assigned elements `${rops[0]}`, `${rops[1]}` and `${rops[2]}`), you get an empty string as the value of `${rops[$i]}`.  What else should the shell give you?

Comment: Thank you,any alternative way compare values in array against a fixed value.

Comment: You've got two: how many more do you need?  What are you really trying to do?